# Xamarin Studio (Forms/Android): Compiling error when assets folder containing subfolder

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I got a compiling error "Cannot copy /Users/...../Subfolder/ to /Users/..../Droid/obj/Debug/assets/Subfolder/, as the source file doesn't exist", if I created a subfolder in assets folder.
How can I use subfolders in assets folder?

Comment: Same error when I create a raw folder at resources with a subdirectory

Comment: I have created the sub folder in Assets folder. It works fine with no compiling error. Can you find out csproj file in your project folder. And check the tag  `<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Assets\NewFolder1\" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Answer (score 0):

What I generally do to solve that problem: I edit the csproj file and I delete the asset folder reference, I keep only the file reference.

For example, replace:

```
<AndroidAsset Include="Assets\assetFolder" />
<AndroidAsset Include="Assets\assetFolder\assetFile.bin" />
```

By only:

```
<AndroidAsset Include="Assets\assetFolder\assetFile.bin" />
```

Comment: hmm I can't find that at my csproj file (test.Droid.csproj) :(

Comment: can you post you're csproj content, just the assets part?

Comment: <MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>Assets</MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix> thats the only "AndroidAssest" Part I found

Comment: From what I understood is you tried to add an assets to you project, isn't it?

Comment: I tried to add an subdirectory to assets, or resources/raw/ then I got the compiling error

Comment: After adding the directory, open your csproj with an editor then remove the folder reference. Keep only the file.

Comment: Then the folder disappears at my project too